# XML reading with multiple child in SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> ```
> <Data>abc</Data>
> <Data>def</Data>
> ```

I want to get data from above tag where child  tag is under Parent  tag  So how to read it into one column in sql server as

### Column1

abc,def

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<parent>
    <Data>abc</Data>
    <Data>def</Data>
</parent>'

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + d.value('.', 'nvarchar(20)')
    FROM @x.nodes('/parent/Data') AS p(d)
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data is contained in a table with column having XML data type.

Lets assume it is inside the table

```
#Test(column1 XML)
```

The values could be retrieved as:

```
Select Column1.Value('(/Parent/Child)[1]','varchar(100)') as FieldName From #Test
```

" [1](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/) " denotes that a scalar value is to be returned.

For more information :
[Pinal Dave Article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

In this case, i am passing XML from .net to Sql . where i am readig it and storing it in SQL.

Comment: <Parent>
<Data>abc</Data>
<Data>def</Data>
</Parent>
This XML i am passing it from .net to SQL , I want to store it under one column in SQL as "abc,def"